# Convert SQL timestamp column to date format column of Python dataframe

Tags: python, excel, pandas, timestamp, date-formatting

I have data upload in MS Excel format.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ojinx.jpg)

This file has a column with dates in "**dd.mm.yyyy 00:00:00**" format.
Reading file with code:

```
df = pd.read_excel('data_from_db.xlsx')
```

I recieve a frame, where dates column has "*object*" type. Further I convert this column to date format by command:

```
df['Date_Column'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date_Column'])
```

That gives me "*datetime64[ns]*" type.

But this command does not work correctly each time. I meet rows with muddled data:

1. somewhere rows have format "yyyy.**mm.dd**",
2. somwhere "yyyy.**dd.mm**".

How should I correctly convert excel column with "**dd.mm.yyyy 00:00:00**" format to column in pandas dataframe with date type and "**dd.mm.yyyy**" fromat?

P.S. Also, I noticed this oddity: some values in raw date column have str type, another - float. But I can't wrap my head around it, because raw table is an upload from database.

Comment: Hey there, welcome to StackOverflow! Please provide some more information, e.g. a sample of your `data_from_db.xlsx`. Have you checked the date format inside the spreadsheet, are they _all_ `'dd.mm.yyyy'`?

Comment: @Finwood thank you for your attention - I uodated question with table image link.

Comment: @OleV.V. thank you for your advice - I've corrected tag

Answer (score 1):

Without specifying a format, `pd.to_datetime` has to guess from the data how a date string is to be interpreted. With default parameters this fails for the second and third row of your data:

```
In [5]: date_of_hire = pd.Series(['18.01.2018 0:00:00',
                                  '01.02.2018 0:00:00',
                                  '06.11.2018 0:00:00'])                    

In [6]: pd.to_datetime(date_of_hire)
Out[6]: 
0   2018-01-18
1   2018-01-02
2   2018-06-11
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

The quickest solution would be to pass `dayfirst=True`:

```
In [7]: pd.to_datetime(date_of_hire, dayfirst=True)
Out[7]: 
0   2018-01-18
1   2018-02-01
2   2018-11-06
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

If you know the complete format of your data, can specify it directly. This only works if the format is *exactly* like given, if a row should e.g. lack the time the conversion will fail.

```
In [8]: pd.to_datetime(date_of_hire, format='%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S')
Out[8]: 
0   2018-01-18
1   2018-02-01
2   2018-11-06
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

In case you should have little information about the date format, except for it being consistent, pandas has the ability to infer the format from the data beforehand:

```
In [9]: pd.to_datetime(date_of_hire, infer_datetime_format=True)
Out[9]: 
0   2018-01-18
1   2018-02-01
2   2018-11-06
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: Thank you @Finwood for your comprehensive information. Your answer is really helpfull! Thanks you and StackOverflow :)

Comment: In this case, please mark the answer as accepted: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers